# Yahoo! Messenger problem with secure HTTP connection after installing FreeVPN or Astrill

Tags: vpn

I installed FreeVPN to access a site restricted only to the USA. I uninstalled it some time later and am using [astrill.com](https://www.astrill.com/) some times.

Either since installing FreeVPN or Astrill, I cannot login with Yahoo! Messenger. I did what the troubleshooting says but I don't have any proxy/port set there and I don't use IE as my default browser, I use Firefox.

Tried to uninstall the Messenger then a clean install. The same thing.

[image: screenshot of troubleshooter dialog]

Comment: Maybe there's some virus scanner that is trying to outsmart you? See if there's any option in your virus scanner to secure Instant Messaging, and if so: temporarily disable that?

Comment: I use Microsoft Security Essentials & Spybot Search&Destroy. I disabled them both, same thing.
I think we're starting to run out of options :(

Comment: I tried to get into Connection Preferences again, but this popped-up http://img717.imageshack.us/img717/4126/capturew.jpg After I pressed ok it did opened the Preferences, but maybe it's saying something. (It's chineese for me)

Comment: Not giving up yet ;-) That error is not very descriptive indeed, but it *might* indicate that your Messenger is using old and new things at the same time. You do not have BOTH version 8 and 10 installed, do you? And: did you ever go into that preferences earlier *without* that error message? And do the preferences indeed state "direct connection"? (To get *something* out of this: when pressing Alt-PrintScreen you'll get a screen capture of just the active window. Just in case you didn't know that.)

Comment: I didn't had both version 8 and 10 before, but I did installed it a few hours ago, so I don't think the 8 version did anything bad. That's my first time I see that error when I try to access the Preferences. Yes, at Connection Preferences the Messenger is set to Connect directly to the Internet. (I'm using the Snipping Tool of Windows 7, but thanks for the PrtScr advice :D )
I think I'll give you the correct answer anyway, because you deserve the 100 bounty points anyway.

Comment: Ok, but still not solved, right?

Comment: No, still not solved :(

Comment: Do you have any choices in the dropdown "Internet connection"? (The one that says "Dial up" in the image http://help.yahoo.com/l/us/yahoo/messenger/messenger9/b-ms9tasignintips-v1a.jpg which is used at http://help.yahoo.com/l/us/yahoo/messenger/messenger10/messenger/ms9tasignintips05.html) And does the setting look alright to you?

Comment: http://img18.imageshack.us/img18/4938/imageivv.jpg I tried all of them, nothing changes.

Comment: Ahh, that's only about speed (probably used to determine the maximum video size and such things), not about the actual network connection. We're running out of options... :-(

Comment: After my exams I always have a fresh install system, so it doesn't matter. I really appreciate u trying to help me. Thanks a lot

Comment: Good luck at the exams then! ;-) (If you ever think of any new details, and then add a comment to something that isn't mine, then please prefix with @Arjan, so I get a notification. No need to add that when commenting to my own answer below. See http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/01/new-improved-comments-with-reply/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I don't have any proxy/port set there and I don't use IE as my default browser, I use Firefox.

Given the troubleshooting screen, I *assume* that (unless set up differently [in Messenger itself](http://help.yahoo.com/l/us/yahoo/messenger/messenger10/messenger/ms9tasignintips05.html)) Yahoo! Messenger uses the same settings as IE. So you might need to change these settings even though for browsing you don't use it. So you'll need to figure out if the VPN you're using provides such proxy server, and then make IE or Messenger use it.

See also Yahoo's [Troubleshooting Tips for Messenger Sign-in Issues](http://help.yahoo.com/l/us/yahoo/messenger/messenger10/messenger/ms9tasignintips.html). If your connection to the web is through a HTTP proxy, then you won't be able to make or receive voice calls with your PC, according to [What ports are used for calling with Yahoo! Messenger?](http://help.yahoo.com/l/us/yahoo/messenger/messenger10/othercomms/othercomms-06.html) But I assume sending text messages should always work.

Note that the details show the problem:

> Resolving host name vcs1.msg.yahoo.com

This [should](http://samspade.org/whois/vcs1.msg.yahoo.com) yield `68.180.216.31`, but you get:

> Connecting to Virtual IP server 127.0.1.5

This `127.0.1.5` is an IP address for a [private network](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network#Reserved_private_IPv4_address_space), not for the internet. So I *assume* that the VPN service you use also uses its own DNS server, to relay all your requests through their own web servers. That DNS server then does not give your browser or Messenger the true IP address, but a private address. This way they can add advertisements, but that also breaks the secure connection that Messenger tries to use ([man-in-the-middle attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack)), and hence Messenger will refuse to operate.

If I am right, then some possible workarounds to make Messenger bypass this service:

- Explicitly use a different DNS server, like [OpenDNS](https://store.opendns.com/setup/) or [Google DNS](http://code.google.com/speed/public-dns/).
- Add the domains that Yahoo! needs to your [hosts file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_file), to map them to Yahoo!'s IP address directly. (But: how to know what domains it needs? And what if they change? Better try a different DNS server.)

Both workarounds might not work at all, if the VPN server you use does not allow for direct access to internet IP addresses. (And I guess they'll indeed disallow that, as relaying your requests is the only way they can add the advertisements.)

Can you provide any details on the exact VPN service you're using? Did you try other secure sites, such as https://gmail.com or some internet banking? And above all: can you access https://login.yahoo.com like suggested in your screen capture, *without* any security warnings? (You can try another browser for a first test as well.)

If you're using `thefreevpn.com` (somehow, I don't really trust that site) then [here](http://thefreevpn.com/forum/index.php?topic=170.0)'s a note from the main developer, which makes me think that HTTPS over its default port should be no problem:

> currently we allow SSH, FTP, HTTP/HTTPS, ICQ.

Comment: I uninstalled the FreeVPN before I even saw that I couldn't log in. But I'm using Astrill.com now.
Any other secure site is working and I can access https://login.yahoo.com without any security warnings.

So, I just add 68.180.216.31 to the windows hosts file ?

Comment: @ChristianM: Did you get `127.0.1.5` with FreeVPN or Astrill? From what I've quickly found on the net, Astrill promotes itself as a VPN, but is really a proxy. As during installation it wants you to close your browsers, *maybe* it has set up a proxy in your browsers? Or maybe it has set up some system-wide proxy? If so, then hopefully you can copy those details into Messenger's preferences as well. But first you must try to get those details... In Firefox, type `about:config` in the location bar (URL bar) and then type `proxy` to quickly see proxy-related settings. Anything there?

Comment: There you go Arjan : http://img12.imageshack.us/img12/5606/capturexb.jpg

Thx for trying to help me.

Comment: Ok, http://img12.imageshack.us/img12/5606/capturexb.jpg shows that Firefox knows about some previous proxy `77.71.0.149` on port `8080`, but the configuration `network.proxy.type = 0` means no proxy is currently enabled. So: if Firefox works fine then that's not because Astrill made it use some proxy. So, did you get `127.0.1.5` with FreeVPN or Astrill? Did Astrill give you any link to some documentation? (By the way: did I rewrite your question correctly?)

Comment: Kinda.. I don't use Astrill all the time. Only when I watch something on that site. So, I don't think Astrill is the problem.
You said Y! Messenger uses the same settings as IE. I can't find any setting that I could even change and test the login. Also, I use a PPPOE connection, my messenger is set tot connect directly to the internet. Any other information I could give you ?

Comment: Another thing, Y! Messenger 8.1 works ok, but still.. I want the last version 10.

Comment: I wrote I *assume* Messenger uses the same settings given the text from your screen capture (but I also linked to a knowledge base article about Messenger's own settings). If you know how to use the command prompt: what IP address does `ping vcs1.msg.yahoo.com` give you? And as you apparently don't use Astrill all the time, and already uninstalled FreeVPN, I guess you need to revise your question a bit...

Comment: Reply from 68.180.216.31: bytes=32 time=208ms TTL=47
Reply from 68.180.216.31: bytes=32 time=208ms TTL=47
Reply from 68.180.216.31: bytes=32 time=208ms TTL=47

Comment: Hmmm, and that Messenger Troubleshooter still refers to something like `127.0.1.5`...? Can you check if there's any specific network settings then? See http://help.yahoo.com/l/us/yahoo/messenger/messenger10/messenger/ms9tasignintips05.html

Comment: By the way: the very same http://help.yahoo.com/l/us/yahoo/messenger/messenger10/messenger/ms9tasignintips05.html confirms that Messenger uses IE's settings, *if* a proxy is enabled in Messenger's preferences. But "Connect directly to the Internet" should do, I guess, which will not rely on any preference in IE. But even if you use a proxy, that does not explain that  `vcs1.msg.yahoo.com` resolves to something like `127.0.1.5` in Messenger. (That is: if I am interpreting that troubleshooter details correctly.)

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to

   > Internet Explorer > Tools > Internet Options > Advanced
2. Click **Restore advanced settings**
3. Click **Reset...** of the *Reset Internet Explorer settings* section

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem a few minutes ago and this is what I did to fix it:

I have both firefox and IE and each one uses a different proxy. Just go to `IE tools > Internet Options > Connections > LAN Settings` and remove the `use proxy` checkbox. Make sure that it's off and now use the yahoo. It should work, and be sure that your yahoo connection setting is set to connect to internet not with http.

Answer (score 0):

It's usually caused by WinHTTP Web Proxy Auto-Discovery Service I guess, make sure it is running or make that service always run automatically